# What could cause a mismatched DCU file?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

When I open my project and I double click on a specific pas file in the Project Manager, bds.exe freezes and continues using 25% of the cpu. I have to kill the process through the Windows Task Manager. (1)

When I open my project and I press F12 on that exact same file, I see what I would have expected to see earlier, the contents of the pas file.

When I open my project and I compile it first, then double click on the file, everything is fine.

I'm trying to figure out how, what I assume to be a mismatched DCU file, snuck into my project and what the best way is to prevent a similar issue in the future. Can I force all DCU files to be rebuilt? Can I simply delete all dcu files and recompile or is that a dangerous thing to do? My DCU files are currently also stored in the same directory where I keep the pas and dfm files, that is a bit messy.

(1) our application also shows behaviour in production where it sometimes crashes while it continues to use a steady cpu usage or simply continues to work as expected but shows a steady cpu usage in the background. We have been unable to trigger it in a compiled version but see it popping up from time to time. We assume the dcu mismatch is at the source of this problem.

Comment: Are you still on XE as you were almost three years ago? In later posts you never indicated which version you use. Point being, have you upgraded the project from an earlier version of Delphi? This can introduce problems. You can build all DCUs of your own making by selecting "Build" instead of "Compile". The project manager has a menu "Clean" that deletes all DCUs. You can also do it manually. Just be sure not to delete any library DCU files.

Comment: I'm still on XE and therefore did not upgrade my project recently.

Comment: No evidence presented here that "mismatched DCU" is the issue. In fact, I've no idea what a mismatched DCU is. Whatever the problem is with your app, you need to debug it to progress. Add madExcept and use madTraceProcess to extract stack traces and more when your app is in its non-terminating loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous issues in your question, some entirely unrelated, but the assumption that the problem is a "mismatched" DCU is unlikely to be correct (by which I presume you mean an "old" or otherwise incorrect DCU compiled in the past or with different source).

First your problems.

### IDE Behaviour

The problem with the IDE locking up when double-clicking a unit in the Project Manager is unlikely to be anything to do with a "mismatched" DCU.

Do you have source files located on a network drive ?  Is this unit such a file ?  Is that network location available/valid ?  i.e. is the path to the file using a network drive letter that is no longer mapped or otherwise not available ?

If there is no explicit path in the unit reference in the DPR, do you have network locations listed in your system, IDE or project PATH ?

Difficulty accessing file locations is the most likely explanation for the IDE appearing to lock up when trying to simply open a file.

As to why it should behave differently when using F12 rather than the Project Manager, unfortunately the Delphi IDE is notorious for using different mechanisms to achieve the same thing in different places so it isn't surprising that sometimes when one of these mechanisms breaks the others still work (and can give different results even when both work).

### Runtime Behaviour of your App

If we work on the basis that you do indeed have a "mismatched" DCU then performing a full build of your project will resolve that mismatch, as long as you have the source for all the required DCU's and that the *correct* and *appropriate* source for each DCU is available.

However, even though the mismatch may be resolved, rebuilding may or may not fix the issue, depending on whether that issue remains in the source code for that unit itself when recompiled.

The simple fact of the DCU being "mismatched" cannot cause aberrant application behaviour.  With the exception of OS or RTL bugs etc, if there are errors in the behaviour of an application then those errors will be the result of *errors in the source code as compiled*.

Simply recompiling source code containing an error will not remove that error.

As such, if there *is* such an error then far more information will be needed if anyone is to be able to give any assistance on that score (and this should be a separate question, once you have done some initial debugging and diagnostics yourself).

### Runtime Packages

If you are using runtime packages then things get more complicated because with a runtime package, the DCU employed for any particular unit could be part of a package file.  In that case, the DCU file on disk is produced *when you compile the package itself* but any project that *uses* that *package* will **not** use the DCU on disk but will instead use the version that has been compiled into the package.

So if you are using runtime packages then as well as rebuilding your project you need to also rebuild any and all runtime packages that may have changed.

Now, for your actual questions.

### Q1: Can I Rebuild all The DCU's ?

Yes, of course.  But see above w.r.t **Runtime Packages**, *if* your project uses them.

I would **strongly** recommend that you change your project settings to output DCU files to a specific location, separate from the source files.

For example, you could have a project specific DCU folder using a relative path.  i.e. set your DCU output folder to something like ".\dcu" and create a dcu folder within the folder where your DPR is located.

For Delphi versions supporting multiple platforms and configurations it is best to include the environment variables for the platform and configuration in that path, so that you don't end up using units compiled for DEBUG in a RELEASE build.

e.g.

```
.\dcu\$(Platform)\$(Config)
```

or

```
.\$(Platform)\$(Config)\dcu
```

**What Is Compiled in a Build ?**

When you do a **Build** on a project (as distinct from a "Compile"), all units referenced by that project will be recompiled, with the exception of any VCL/RTL units (i.e. those provided with Delphi).  Those get special treatment.

At a minimum, rebuilding a project will forcibly recompile all units explicitly listed in the DPR, but will also recompile **all** other units that are used by those units (or units that they use etc etc).

**NOTE: DCU's With Missing Source**

A unit will *only* be recompiled **if** *the source can be located*.

If you have a DCU and the source file is missing or cannot be located on the project, IDE or system path, then the compiler will simply assume that you want to use the existing DCU.

This is the case even with a full "Build".

### 3rd Party DCU's

It may seem obvious but you should also be careful that you don't delete DCU's that may be your only copy of any 3rd party libraries you may be using for which you do not have the source.

This is highly inadvisable, but I guess we mustn't rule out the possibility that you may be in this situation.

### Q2: Should I Delete all the DCU's ?

In general, yes.  As noted above, even a full build will be successful if you are missing the source code for a unit that is referenced, as long as there is a DCU (or required package, if using runtime packages) that can be found.

So the only way to be sure that you have the current source for **all** DCU's is to first delete the DCU's that any previous builds may have used.

This is of course much easier when you have a specific, explicit location in which all your project DCU's are output.

It's slightly more involved **if** you are using **Runtime Packages**, though if you are organising your DCU's sensibly then the only real complication is that you need to repeat the same exercise for all the projects involved, working through starting each of the runtime packages that are used and finishing with the projects that in turn use them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can rebuild all DCU files in your project;

In the project group window, right click on the project and select Build.

It is OK to delete all DCUs in your project, but not necessary (or desirable in case you make a mistake...).

Note that this only builds DCUs explicitly in you project (as shown in your project tree) not any implicit ones imported as a result of your uses clauses.

Comment: Unless of course there are DCU's *where you do not have the source*.  Which is still perhaps "OK" (if you don't have the source you **need** to get it, find it or recreate it so finding out which source(s) are missing is A Good Thing) but potentially not the *entirely* risk free exercise you seem to suggest.  e.g. if you are using a 3rd party DCU provided without source you better have a backup of that DCU somewhere before you blow it away.  Also a "Build" **will** also recompile **implicitly** used DCU's, as long as the PAS source is findable (on the system, IDE or project paths).

Answer (score 0):

Three things may be going on that have not been adressed in other answers.
Note that I only have experience with Delphi XE2 and Seattle 10, but they may apply to your version.

1. Delphi can be slow when switching from form to source view, especially if you have many components on your form. In migrating from XE2 to 10, we noticed an improvement here. We are talking seconds here, this does not seem to be your issue.
2. Delphi can be notoriously slow when switching between projects. After a switch the IDE can take a very long time (20-30 seconds) to respond. You cannot type anything; code completion takes a long time; initiating a project search with Alt-S-D waits a long time, then fails. In migrating from XE2 to 10, we noticed a large deterioration here.
3. **Conditional compilation**. If you have IFDEFs in your code compiling stuff for one project but not for another, your IDE can hang completely, and there's nothing else you can do then killing BDS.EXE. This happens in Delphi Seattle 10 if you switch projects and accidentally **Compile** instead of **Build**.

You may experience variations of these.